# Консоль выводит только половину от того, что должна вывести

Tags: c#, консоль

У меня есть некий метод:

```
private static void DecodeMessage(string[] lines)
    {
        string text = string.Empty, result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = lines.Length; i != 0; i--)
            text += String.Format($"{lines[--i]} ");

        string[] words = text.Split(' ');

        for (int c = 0; c < words.Length; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{c}] — {words[c]}");
        }
    }
```

В параметры метода DecodeMessage передаётся массив, хранящий в себе:

> {"решИла нЕ Упрощать и зашифРОВАтЬ Все послаНИЕ", "дАже не Старайся нИЧЕГО у тЕбя нЕ получится с расшифРОВкой", "Сдавайся НЕ твоего ума Ты не споСОбЕн Но может быть", "если особенно упорно подойдешь к делу", "", "будет Трудно конечнО", "Код ведЬ не из простых", "очень ХОРОШИЙ код", "то у тебя все получится", "и я буДу Писать тЕбЕ еще", "", "чао"}

По какой-то причине при запуске программы без отладчика (Ctrl+F5) на консоль выводит только половину. А при запуске программы с отладчиком, делая по одному шагу, на консоль выводится всё правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чём суть сей проблемы?**

Comment: 15 из 58 - это слегка не половина, и даже немного не треть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С отладчиком тоже не работает, либо, быть может вы отлаживаете не последнюю версию кода. Пересоберите проект, перезапустите студию, кроме шуток - иногда и это помогает.

Ну и как уже замечено, вы декрементируете счетчик дважды. Но я бы написал проще.

```cs
private static void DecodeMessage(string[] lines)
{
    string text = string.Join(" ", lines.Reverse());

    string[] words = text.Split();

    for (int c = 0; c < words.Length; c++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{c}] — {words[c]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Пересобрал проект и перезагрузил студию - не помогло. Ваш способ решения и правда короче, но он работает так же по неизвестным мне обстоятельствам. Я правил вопрос, прикрепив фотографию

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов окей, закройте студию, удалите папки bin и obj внутри каталога проекта, и попробуйте еще раз. Вы не находите подозрительным, что мой, совершенно по-другому написанный код работает так же как и ваш, что технически невозможно?

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов судя по скриншоту, вывод нормальный, но изменены настройки консоли, вследствие чего вывод просто не помещается в буфер консоли. Кем изменены настройки cmd.exe и зачем - мне неизвестно. Другими словами, скриншот говорит нам, что у вас именно с консолью что-то не то, а не с кодом. А в отладчике работает, потому что у студии по-своему настроенная консоль.

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов чтобы убедиться, на следующей строчке после `Console.WriteLine` в цикле вывода, напишите например `Thread.Sleep(300);` и вы увидите в режиме реального времени, как выводятся все значения.

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов вы случаем не задаете WindowSize / BufferSize консоли програмно? Если да, то уберите эти настройки из кода и перепроверьте.

Comment: И правда, дело было в маленьком значении буфера консоли. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

```
        for (int i = lines.Length; i != 0; i--)
                                           ^^^ один
            text += String.Format($"{lines[--i]} ");
                                           ^^^ два
```

Вы два раза декрементируете переменную цикла `i` - один раз в конструкции цикла `for` и другой раз уже внутри цикла. Поэтому вы проскакиваете половину значений.

Comment: это правильно, но почему "с отладчиком все работает"?

Comment: Не знал, что при использовании переменной в указании индекса массива она изменяется как бы ссылочно (не пинайте), думал, что она копирует значение. Однако, это не исправило проблему!

Comment: "с отладчиком всё работает" — так и есть. Когда я запускаю программу в отладчике и смотрю на то, как она работает по шагам, тогда программа выводит все значения

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов Не важно, где вы используете переменную, префиксный/постфиксный инкремент/декремент всегда пишет изменённое значение обратно в переменную, а не только отдаёт значение до/после инкремента/декремента наружу.